# How to include LESS in specific page layout

Tags: magento2, layout, less, page-layouts

I have created my custom page_layout in magento 2 and now I want to add some less only in my page_layout. I don't want to load those less file in other layouts.

How I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

As per as magento , *you cannot use a less file layout specific*.

But **you can make CSS file page layout specific.**

Suppose, you have created a module and you want to call a CSS file for Product details page, Then at  `app/code/{Vendorname}/{MOduleName}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/mycustom.css" after="-" />
    </head>
</page>
```

SO, you have to create one less file `mycustom.lesss` and one css file `mycustom.css` at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{MOduleName}/view/frontend/web/css`.

Note the CSS file content should empty but the less have content.

After that if you will do static content `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` then at **pub static folder the CSS file will be created**.

Comment: I have a question  in this why we should leave empty the .css file what is the use of it here can we only use the .less file?

Comment: chrul, i have created the empty css file as when static content deploy then less converyed content  copied  that css file. If i don't  create empty css file then less css does not copied over css file.

Comment: ok you means when deployment in process then less content will be copied to .css empty file?

Comment: yes, you are right. It will copy to css

Comment: @AmitBera Can I add css or less in page_layout file. I want to implement my design in all the pages using my page_layout(eg. 2columns-left).

Comment: You have to add css file  not less file