# Magento 2.4 Commerce cloud - After push the code from dev to live server less not compiled to css file

Tags: less, magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I have created a custom theme, for the listing page i have created custom less file,

**app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Catalog\web\css\source\ _custom_listing_page.less**

On the Website listing page my **_custom_listing_page.less** not working. which means not compiled into CSS file.

I have declared my **_custom_listing_page.less** in **app\design\frontend\Zero\sleepworld\my_theme\layout\catalog_category_view.xml**

```
   <head>        
   <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/source/_custom_listing_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>
```

Console error - CSS file : canceled

[image]

Note : Local working good, when i move to live then i am getting the error.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241838/how-to-include-less-in-specific-page-layout This will help you

Answer (score 0):

Your **catalog_category_view.xml** should be something like this;

```
<head>        
   <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/custom_listing_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: But i created with underscore right "_custom_listing_page.less", should i remove in xml file?

Comment: Its better to rename the custom less file without underscore. Because _ means these files will be used main wrapper less file and imported in.

Comment: Understood your point, let me remove that, before i will ask one query, in localhost everything good, less compiled to css everything good, when i move to the live server there i am getting an error, any specific reason for this.